# Doctrine2 DiscriminatorMap can be optional / automatic to fit children class + namespace?

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle, discriminator

I have an abstract entity model class that have inheritance type "joined".

If I want to extend that entity in another bundle, I need to add the "children class" into the discriminator map .. But if its in another bundle, that means I will need to modify the parent bundle entity every time that I want to extend that model into another bundle, and I think that this does make a little sense.

So if I want to not need to modify the abstract class discriminator map every time that I extend it with a new entity in a new bundle, is it possible to say Doctrine or SF2 that the **"discr" field must equal the children entity class name + its namespace**, so this way **it will be way more dynamic** so I **don't have to edit my parent bundle every time that I want to extend it**.

Mapped superclass is not a good option because I need one-to-many relationship.

So my question is clearly : How I can avoid to manually set "DiscriminatorMap" so that field be automatically set to the children class name + namespace ? (discr = inherited class name + namespace)

This is example that would be cool :

```
/**
* Operable
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(**AUTOMATIC**)
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FOO\PaymentBundle\Entity\OperableRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
abstract class Operable     {
    /* some good stuff */
}
```

Thank you very much to all of you and have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

After taking time to carefully read the doc, the solution is way very simple :

**Simply to remove "@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn" annotation from there !**

> The names of the classes in the discriminator map do not need to be
>   fully qualified if the classes are contained in the same namespace as
>   the entity class on which the discriminator map is applied.
>
> If no discriminator map is provided, then the map is generated
>   automatically.     The automatically generated discriminator map
>   contains the lowercase short name of each class as key.
>
> (source : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: This applies to `targetEntity` as well. As long as you have two classes within same namespace you can safely omit the it ;)